# Windows 7 - Moving windows around

Tags: windows-7, themes

I am using windows 7. I am not sure why but from some reason when I drag windows around I no longer see them moving in action. Instead I see an outline of the window moving around. It is once I let go of the mouse that the actual windows positions updates. How can get realtime windows moving updates?

I tried to reset the theme but that does not work.

[image]

Comment: Open the [Visual Effects settings](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1908-visual-effects-settings-change.html). Is the **Show window contents while dragging** option disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

1. Click on Start, type **adjust appearance** in the search box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Under the **Visual Effects** tab, enable the **Show window contents while dragging** option.
3. Apply the changes, and click **OK**.